# Error while trying folding(foldr()) in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am struggling with trying to implement the foldr() function, the function I made in the code shown below, which is a function to multiply every element in an array by 2 but it gave me an error message(shown below too), and I don't quite know how to fix it. I am open to suggestions, so any tips or fixes will greatly help. Thanks
**Here is the source code**

```
multwo ::[a] -> [a]
multwo = foldr(\x acc-> (2*x):acc)[]
```

**Here is the error message**

```
  • No instance for (Num a) arising from a use of ‘*’
      Possible fix:
        add (Num a) to the context of
          the type signature for:
            multwo :: forall a. [a] -> [a]
    • In the first argument of ‘(:)’, namely ‘(2 * x)’
      In the expression: (2 * x) : acc
      In the first argument of ‘foldr’, namely
        ‘(\ x acc -> (2 * x) : acc)’

  |
9 | multwo = foldr(\x acc-> (2*x):acc)[]
  |                          ^^^
```

Comment: you could comment out the type signature and it would work, and even told you the type, by itself.

Answer (score 1):

Your `multwo` function aims to multiply all elements with two, but that is only possible if this is a list of numbers. Haskell has the [**`Num`** typeclass](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Num) to group all number types. You thus should add a type constraint to the signature:

```
multwo :: Num a => [a] -> [a]
multwo = foldr (\x acc-> (2*x) : acc) []
```

You can shorten the folding function further to:

```
\x -> (2*x :)
```

and further to:

```
(:) . (2 *)
```

so a shorter implementation looks like:

```
multwo :: Num a => [a] -> [a]
multwo = foldr ((:) . (2*)) []
```